# Spring (DataSourceTransactionManager) @Transactable doesn't roll back

Tags: java, spring, transactions, datasource

I'm trying to configure Spring Transactions but they seem not to work.

This is my config Java Class where I give definitions to Datasource, JdbcTemplates and all the Daos that I use

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("${configuration.properties.path}")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BeanConfiguration  {

...different DAOs...


    @Override
    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MyManager myManager(){
        return new MyManager();
    }
}
```

This is the class MyManager that has Transactible methods and operates with multiple DAOs.

```
//@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)

public class EnoceanDeviceManager{

....autowired Daos

public void addNewDevices(Class1 class1, Class2 class2) {

        //returns with id
        class1 = 1dao.push(class1);

        class2.setClass1(class1);

        class2 = 2dao.push(class2); //can throw exception   
      }
}
```

I want that DB changes made with the help of 1dao do not occure if the method dao.push throws an Exception. There is no try-catches within DAO-level.
This is the class where I use one exemplar of MyManager to push a pair of objects together:

```
  public class TestEnoceanDeviceManager extends BigClassForTestsWITHCOnfigurations{

  @Atowired
  MyManager myManager;

  @Test
      //the method
      public void testAddNewDevices(){

            .... defining class1 and class2....

            myManager.addNewDevices(class1, class2);
      }
  }
```

As a result the method `testAddNewDevices` only throws a non-catched Exception from `2dao.push()` method and doesn't log about rolling back. I tried to catch an Exception on different levels, but there is still no rolling back.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all your code doesn't make sense. `@ContextConfiguration` is for testing, the same goes for `@TransactionConfiguration` for a normal bean this doesn't do anything. I also wonder why the `testAddNewDevices` should do anything because there is no annotations nor is it a Spring unit test. So I'm not sure what you are trying to do but what you posted here is confusing at best.

Comment: @M.Deinum It is a test class and id works like a test class, but it does not see Transactable in inner methods.

Comment: And it never will as that is how Spring AOP works. It isn't a Spring based test class as `@ContextConfiguration` by itself doesn't do a thing. Also the `@ContextConfiguration` on a `@Service` class doesn't make sense either. So you are mixing up a lot of things and those things don't make sense mixing. Seems like you need some studying to do...

Comment: I'm not a professor of Spring... But without context configuration and service annotations it doesn't work as well.

Comment: The `@Service` is correct the others (apart from `@Transactional`) don't make sense.